# what I need study to create gears that can control out of Blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm wanting create a 3D model where there four gears that need rotate, but I need have control of this rotation by code out of blender, in other code language, what I need study to create gears that can control?

Comment: Blender uses Python as it's main scripting language, I would suggest using that as the language you use to control the gears. Raspberry Pi also uses python as it's scripting language, and I have had many success over the years controlling gears and step motors with it using python scripts.

Comment: But, by example, I need import a blender model to a game engine, this engine don't use python, and a need control the gears by code, how to make this?

Comment: If you just use blender just for modeling, I think your answer depends on the game engine capabilities. I don't see how can blender be involved in this. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you're bringing it into a game engine, shouldn't you just export the models only and code their movement/interaction (physics, collisions, rotation, etc..) in the game engine itself? There is no need to code the rotation in blender and then "port" the code over to the engine - just code it in the engine, I think it would be better suited anyway,

Comment: so, a I need separate all parts of my model, and import they separated in the engine, and in the engine connect all parts and make the moviment?

Comment: Depends on the project and the engine, but that would be one relatively common approach. Game engines are built to handle complex movement/interaction between objects. It all depends.. how many objects would you have to separate and reconnect? If it's a large number, then maybe finding a different approach is warranted. May I ask what engine you're exporting it to?

Comment: I need export to Webots and print in 3D, the four gears are connected with one central gear that need rotate by a motor (so, I think that only need control the speed of the this motor, and the rest of rotation can be with "fix rotation"), so, the four gears move more four legs by eccentrics.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/cyberbotics/blender-webots-exporter, so, Can I make the rotation em blender that will export?